# C program to print numbers between 100 and 1000 which sum of digit is 20

Tags: c, for-loop

I am writing a C program which should display me all numbers between 100 and 1000 which sum of digit is 20. I tried this code down here, but it just displays 0 as an ouput when I compile it, can you help me? I also tried moving if(iVsota==20) outside of the while loop. I am using Orwell Dev C++ IDE.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int iVnos=0;
    int iOstanek=0;
    int iVsota=1;
    int iStevec1=100;

    for(iStevec1=100; iStevec1<1000; iStevec1++)
    {
        while(iStevec1>0)
        {
            iOstanek=iStevec1%100;
            iStevec1=iStevec1/10;
            iVsota=iOstanek+iVsota;
            if(iVsota==20)
            {
                printf("%i\n", iStevec1);
            }
        }
    }
    return(0);
```

I hope this is better.

Comment: You're using `iStevec1` in both loops. This logic is completely wrong! Once it reaches 0, you'll increment it to 1 in the outer loop, and back to 0 in the inner loop (and it will continue running forever, since the outer loop stops only when it reaches `iStevec1 == 1000`).

Comment: take another approach, put the number in a char buffer[] then extract each character and subtract with '0' that way you get all digits. preferably put that in a separate function e.g. `int sumOfDigits(int number);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Changed the variable names so it's more readable)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add_digits(int n) {
    static int sum = 0;

    if (n == 0)
       return 0;

    sum = n%10 + add_digits(n/10);
    return sum;

}

int main() {

    int start, end;
    start = 100, end = 1000;

    for(start = 100; start <= end; start++) {

        if(add_digits(start) == 20)
            printf("Number: %d\n", start);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

EDIT:

(Your code fixed with comments as explanation)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int iVnos=0;
    int iOstanek=0;
    int iVsota=0;
    int iStevec1=100;
    int temp;  //temp needed

    for(iStevec1=100; iStevec1<=1000; iStevec1++)
    {

        temp =iStevec1; //assign number to temp
        iVsota=0;  //set sum every iteration to 0
        while(temp>0)
        {
            iOstanek=temp%10;  //You need only % 10 to get the last digit of a number
            temp = temp / 10;  //'delete' last digit of the number
            iVsota+=iOstanek;  //add digit to sum

        }

         if(iVsota==20)  //You only need to check the digits after sum is calculated
                printf("Number %d\n", iStevec1);

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: you dont need start = 100; in for loop Or else don't initialize it.

Comment: @almasshaikh I know! It's more a habit from me :D But i want it to make clear that the for loop starts with 100 and ends with 1000 (Also my main goal is it to make the code easy to read and to understand what's going on)

Comment: It would be better for me if you would tell me what have I done wrong... but this is also great.

Comment: @Janac9 It's hard to tell for me if i don't see English names, a few thing i can spot is you don't have a tmp variable so if you overwrite `iStevec1` your loop doesn't count correctly!

Comment: @Janac9 Updated my answer with your code working! Also added comments to explain what's wrong/ what you needed! Hope it helps

Comment: Wish you the same. Just need to understand what is the purpose of that temp variable :) It is like keeping the number?

Comment: @Janac9 Yes because if you modify the real number the loop doesn't work!

Comment: Okay I did. One more thing, if I want display digits, I tried that: iOstanek=iVnos%10;
printf("%i", iOstanek);
iVnos=iVnos/10;       It displays them in wrong order...

Comment: @Janac9 Yep that's correct! Because you go trough from behind! With %10 you get the last digit!

Comment: So there is no way to print them from the front? Thank you!

Comment: @Janac9 It's possible with recursion!

Answer (score 2):

Your loop should look like :

```
  for(iStevec1=100; iStevec1<1000; iStevec1++)
    {
      int c2 = iStevec1/100; // extract third digit
      int c1 = (iStevec1%100)/10; // extract second digit
      int c0 = (iStevec1%10); // extract first digit
      if((c0+c1+c2)==20) // sum and verify
        {
          printf("%i\n", iStevec1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more generalised method to get the sum of all individual numbers in an integer (assumes positive integers):

```
int getSumOfDigits(int x)
{
    int sum = 0;
    while (x > 0)
    {
        sum += x % 10;
        x = x / 10;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 100; i <= 1000; i++)
    {
        if (getSumOfDigits(i) == 20)
        {
            printf("%d\n", x);
        }
    }    
}
```

The expression `x % 10` is the last digit in the integer.  Hence, that's what we add. Then we chop off the last digit in the integer by dividing it by 10.  Repeat until we hit zero.

Comment: I have written that code myself and then thought it would be awesome to just replace the number entered with a counter...             Thank you!

Comment: The down votes are probably because this site is full of nit pickers (though in this case even nit picking couldn't explain it because the answer is essentially correct). But it makes a good point not answering questions that embed very little challenge (to yourself) or interest (to the general community).

Answer (score 0):

Just change 1 thing and you will get what you want

```
    int main (void)
    {
        int iVnos=0;
        int iOstanek=0;
        int iVsota=1;
        int iStevec1=100;
        int temp;
        for(iStevec1=100; iStevec1<1000; iStevec1++)
        {
            temp = iStevec1;
            while(temp>0)
            {
                iOstanek=temp%100;
                temp=temp/10;
                iVsota=iOstanek+iVsota;
                if(iVsota==20)
                {
                    printf("%i\n", iStevec1);
                }
            }
        }
        return(0);
}
```

Enjoy Coding Enjoy Life...

Answer (score 0):

Alternative method, taking advantage of the specifics.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int c0, c1, c2; /* 3 digits sum to 20 */
    for(c0 = 2; c0 < 10; c0++){
        c1 = 11 - c0;
        c2 = 9;
        while(c1 < 10){
            printf("%d%d%d\n", c0, c1, c2);
/* or       printf("%3d\n", (c0*10+c1)*10+c2); */
            c1++;
            c2--;
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```